# Notation on symmetric groups and their representations

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

I am trying to do an exercise of proving that the representation:

$$\mathcal{H} = \{ \left(\begin{smallmatrix}a \\ b \\ c \end{smallmatrix}\right) \in \mathbb{C}^3 : a + b + c = 0 \}$$

is an irreducible representation of the symmetric group $S_3$, but i must admit that i am not comfortable with the notation above. What exactly does it mean? Should it be read as 'Let the Hilbert space contain the set of vectors $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a \\ b \\ c \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ spanning the three dimensional complex space where each vectors elements must sum to zero'? If this is not correct, then what does this notation really mean? Why does $a+b+c=0$ need to be fulfilled, and what consequences does it come with? How is this even a representation?

I understand that when we let a group act on a vector space we get a representation of the group. How is the above equal to letting the group $S_3$ act on the vector space $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a \\ b \\ c \end{smallmatrix}\right) \in \mathbb{C}^3$ ?

I also understand that the $S_3$ group has 6 elements, and that these elements do not commute mutually, therefore the group is non-abelian. Apparently the $S_3$ has the trivial irreducible representation $\mathcal{H} = \mathbb{C} |0\rangle$ which means that each group element acts trivially with the 1x1 identity: $R_{\pi}|0\rangle = |0\rangle$ where i assume that $R_{\pi}$ is the group generator. Once again i do not see how this notation makes sense how can $\mathbb{C}$ act on a vector? Some clear examples and/or explanations of the notation in general is very welcome. Also some hints on how to solve my exercise are welcome.

EDIT: This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346534/explicitly-decompose-mathbbc3-into-irreducible-representations-of-s-3?rq=1) is quite similar, but does not answer my question regarding notation, and getting a deeper understanding through some examples of how this works overall.

Comment: See [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346534/explicitly-decompose-mathbbc3-into-irreducible-representations-of-s-3?rq=1). Do you recognise $V$ there?

Comment: Yes i have looked at that question, and i also added it as an edit in the end of my own quesiton. I believe that $V$ is my $\mathcal{H}$, but i do not see how it is a two dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}$? First of all i thought it was in three dimensions, second what does $x1+x2+x3=0$ mean/do?

Comment: "Hilbert space"?

Comment: $V=\Bbb C^3$ is a representation for $S_3$, under the action of permutation of the components, but is not irreducible. The subspace $U$ where the components add to zero is preserved by $S_3$, and is an irreducible representation.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown It's a difficult task when learning math to determine which symbols are meant to have fixed meaning.  But in any case, yes, $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space and the $S_3$ action is by orthogonal transformations.

Comment: @KyleMiller I suppose $\Bbb C^3$ can be given a Hilbert space structure, but it is quite irrelevant for the matter in hand.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Except for completeness, the standard Hilbert space structure is what makes the trivial subrepresentation so obviously orthogonal to the 2D subrepresentation.  Some people, who tend to be physicists, say "Hilbert space" rather than saying anything about an "inner product."  My point is just that it's not completely irrelevant to mention.

Comment: Ah okay thank you all for your replies. So the colon means that we are talking about a subspace for which the condition $a+b+c=0$ must be fulfilled. That makes much more sense. So the vector $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a \\ b \\ c \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is spanning $\mathbb{C}^3$, but we will look at the specific set of elements for which $a+b+c=0$ and i then need to show that this exact representation is irreducible. Is that understood correctly?

Comment: @CuriousGeorge I read colon as "such that."  So $\{a\in X:p\}$ is read "the set of all $a$ in $X$ such that $p$ is true."  In this case, since it is a solution space to a system of homogeneous linear equations, the set happens to be a vector space, too.  Your use of the word "spanning" should be replaced with "an element of" or "in," but other than that it sounds like you understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symmetric group $S_3$ acts on $\mathbb{C}^3$ by permuting the variables $\sigma(e_i)=e_{\sigma(i)}$ where $e_i$ are the standard coordinate vectors
$$e_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\;,\;e_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\;,\;e_3=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Now, the subspace spanned by $e_1+e_2+e_3$ is obviously $S_3$ invariant, and the complement $\mathcal{H}$ at the top of your post is also clearly $S_3$-invariant. For example
$$(12).\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}b\\a\\c\end{pmatrix}$$
and $a+b+c=0$ if, and only if, $b+a+c=0$.

It has a basis given by the vectors
$$
\alpha_1=e_1-e_2=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\mbox{and}\;\alpha_2=e_2-e_3=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
If you are careful, you will find that the action of $(12)$ on the basis $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2\}$ is $\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and the matrix for $(23)$ is $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: This is really clear and well explained, thank you so much. I did not fully catch the last part though, where you say it has a basis given by $e_1 - e_2$ and $e_2 - e_3$ why is this?. How and why do you suddenly go from 3 to 2 dimensions when writing out the matrices?

Comment: On the list of "Linear representation theory of symmetric groups" on wiki, i can see that $S_3$ has three irreducible representations. Two of degree 1 (i guess that one of them is the trivial representation, and the other?), and one of degree 2, which might be related to what you are trying to explain to me?

Comment: The subspace $\mathcal{H}$ is a $2$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}^3$, right? So a basis for $\mathcal{H}$ consists of two linearly independent vectors. You may verify directly that $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are linearly independent and belong to $\mathcal{H}$. Therefore, $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2\}$ a basis for $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: Sadly i do not see why $\mathcal{H}$ is (or needs to be) a 2-dim subspace of $\mathbb{C}^3$. We started with a 3-dim vector, but argue that the solution-space (the subspace $\mathcal{H}$) of the condition $a+b+c=0$ is 2-dim. This is not clear to me. If i can understand how you arrive or motivate the basis and their connection to the original 6 3x3 matrices that make up $S_3$ maybe it would make sense. I can see that this is called the standard representation of $S_3$ and is exactly what i am trying to learn.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}^3=\mathcal{H}\oplus\mathrm{span}_{\mathbb{C}}(e_1+e_2+e_3)$, so $\mathcal{H}$ is $2$-dimensional. Alternatively, solve $a+b+c=0$ for $b$ to get $b=-a-c$. Then, any $v=\begin{pmatrix}a\\-a-c\\c\end{pmatrix}\in\mathcal{H}$ can be expressed as $v=a\alpha_1-c\alpha_2$.

Comment: After working with it for a while, I can see that the span of the subspace of course needs to be 2-dim since the criteria $a+b+c=0$ fixes one dimension, and we are left with only two linearly independent vectors - hence 2-dim subspace. I can not seem to see the logical jump to the 2x2 matrices though. No matter how i turn it around, i can not see how i can represent any of the actions as 2x2 matrices. The basis $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2\}$ is made up of for example the two 3-dim vectors $(1,-1,0)$ and $(0,1,-1)$. and any vector can be expressed $v = a\alpha_1-c\alpha_2$, how then the 2x2 matrices?

Comment: A linear transformation $\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$ (such as left multiplication by $(12)$) can be represented as a $2\times2$ matrix since $\mathcal{H}$ is 2-dimensional.

Comment: I am really trying to understand, but after so many hours of being stuck i believe i am confusing myself even more. We have 2 vectors in the basis, hence it is 2-dim - but we still have 3 components! I can see it spans a 2-dim plane, but If i try writing out the set of equations i get: $a(1,-1,0)+b(0,1,-1) = 0$ which gives the three equations $a=0$ and $-a+b=0$ and $-b=0$. Which implies everything is zero. If instead taking $z=-x-y$ we get $x(e_1 - e_3)+y(e_2 - e_3)$ written out explicitly. This gives me the basis $B=x(1,0,-1)+y(0,1,-1)$ but i really see no way of making this a 2x2 matrix.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many components the vector has. Choosing a basis (e.g. $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2\}$) defines an isomorphism $\mathcal{H}\to \mathbb{C}^2$ via $\alpha_1\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\alpha_2\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$. Now, in these coordinates $(12).\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $(12).\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$. Hence, the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Notation-wise, $\mathcal{H}$ is simply the vector space consisting of solutions to the homogeneous linear equation $a+b+c=0$.  More compactly, you might see something like $$\mathcal{H}=\{v\in\mathbb{C}^3:\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\end{bmatrix}v=0\}$$

Recall that $S_3$ is the group of permutations of three objects.  Linearizing this, $S_3$ acts on $\mathbb{C}^3$ by permuting the standard basis vectors.  The thing about this particular representation is that the vector $(1,1,1)\in \mathbb{C}^3$ is invariant under the $S_3$ action (and in particular it is simultaneously an eigenvector of all six matrices).  This one-dimensional subspace is called the *trivial representation*, and it turns out one can eliminate it by taking the orthogonally complementary subspace to it, since the $S_3$ action consists of unitary matrices.  The result is your $\mathcal{H}$.

To check more directly that it is a representation, just observe that if you take a vector whose coordinates sum to zero, and then permute the coordinates, the coordinates still sum to zero.

I'll leave irreducibility to you, but a possible hint is that, given any nonzero vector in $\mathcal{H}$, there is a sequence of permutations and linear combinations you can do to create a basis for all of $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes a lot of sense. Just to be sure $a,b,c$ still correspond to some numbers that we scale the unit vector (1,1,1) with, right? So if this is taken to be a Hilbert space, would the sum $a+b+c$ correpond to the inner product of the vector with itself? meaning $(a*,b*,c*) (a,b,c)^T = a*a+b*b+c*c=0$. If so, can this be understood better? Why is this subspace interesting besides that it is a building block/irreducible?

Comment: The all-ones vector is something of a red herring.  The subspace of all vectors $(a,a,a)$, for varying $a$, is the trivial representation (the $S_3$ action has this as a common eigenspace, and the common eigenvector is $1$).  The sum $a+b+c$ corresponds to an inner product with the all-ones vector.  (If you did your suggestion, you'd get the zero-dimensional subspace because the only vector whose length is zero is the zero vector.)

Comment: Irreducible subrepresentations are a generalization of eigenspaces.  By some general theory, the $\mathbb{C}^3$ representation decomposes into irreducible subrepresentations.  We already see the eigenspace one, and it's worth figuring out what is going on with the complementary 2D one.  Spoiler: it's the standard 2D representation of the dihedral group for the triangle.